# Trouble with computed column in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, calculated-columns, subquery

I have a table that I wish to select a subset of columns from but also add on the end a computed column based upon where you are located in a queue.  There are the following fields (that are pertinent):

id:  int, auto increment, primary key
answertime:  datetime, nullable

By default, when something is submitted to the queue, its answertime is NULL.  So, I wish to select the ID of the thing in the queue as well as its rank in the queue (i.e. rank 1 is the next item that is unanswered, etc).  Here's what I was thinking:

rank - id - COUNT(ids below my id where answertime is not null).  However, I'm having an issue with the syntax of this query:

```
SELECT id AS outerid, COUNT(
    SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE id<outerid AND answertime IS NOT NULL
)
FROM tablename 
WHERE answertime IS NULL;
```

Now, obviously, this is wrong because I'm fairly confident you can't embed a select inside of an aggregate function, likewise flipping the SELECT and COUNT doesn't work as you can't embed a SELECT at that point in the code (it can only be used in a WHERE clause).

Is this even possible to do with just SQL or do I need to add some logic on the program end?

If it helps, I'm doing this on SQL Server 2008, although I doubt that would add any value.

Comment: NO time to give a good example but look up the ROW_NUMBER function.  If I have understood you correctly, I think it will be what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that, you just can't use `SELECT *` in an aggregate sub-query. Try this, which gets the `COUNT` value as a scalar result:

```
SELECT
   id AS outerid,
   (SELECT COUNT(Id) FROM tablename
    WHERE id<outie.id AND answertime IS NOT NULL)
FROM tablename outie
WHERE answertime IS NULL;
```

You may need to choose for yourself between using `COUNT(*)`, `COUNT(Id)` or some other column depending on what you're really after.

Comment: Ah, I see what I was missing when I tried the inner SELECT query; I missed the FROM tablename outie bit so it could differentiate between the IDs.  Thanks!

Comment: Or `(SELECT COUNT(answertime) FROM tablename WHERE id < outie.id)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT id AS outerid,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tablename WHERE id < outerid AND answertime IS NOT NULL) AS othercol
FROM tablename -- ?
WHERE answertime IS NULL;
```

also, where's the FROM statement?

Comment: I added the FROM statement to the question; I simplified this from my actual query and neglected to put that in there.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @HLGEM, you could use `ROW_NUMBER()` to obtain your results. The method involves ranking the rows in `tablename` by `id` without partitioning *and* by `id` with partitioning by `answertime`. The difference between the rankings for every row where `answertime` is NULL would give you the same value as the one you are calculating using `COUNT()` in the subquery.

Here's an implementation of the method:

```
;
WITH ranked AS (
  SELECT
    *,
    Rnk     = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (                        ORDER BY id),
    PartRnk = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY answertime ORDER BY id)
  FROM tablename
)
SELECT
  id,  /* AS outerid, if you like */
  Cnt = Rnk - PartRnk
FROM ranked
WHERE answertime IS NULL
```